# There are no accounts registered with Xcode reported during archive even though there is

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, release, signing

Hi I am trying to build an iOS app with Cordova.

The project successfully builds but when I try to release in order to upload to TestFlight with:

```
sudo cordova build ios --release --device --automaticProvisioning --packageType="app-store"
```

Then I get the error

> error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target '' from project '')
>
> error: No profiles for 'com.' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.'. (in target '' from project '')

But I do have an account and the appropriate certificates and profiles.

[Xcode account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Guz.png)

[Debug profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TO2P.png)

[Build settings - Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYBnH.png)

[Release Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GWFf.png)

Comment: In Build Settings: your `Code Signing Identity` for **Release** is set to `iOS Developer`. Shouldn't it be `iOS Distribution`? And a `Provision Profile` is set to automatic, shouldn't you assign it to a specific one?

Comment: Hi Aleksey thanks for the comment. As far as I understand no the iOs Developer is the way to go since you need to sign it for release. It will be re-signed for distribution afterwards. Nevertheless I have tried to do have iOS Distribution and manual selections in all combinations possible. I have been trying this for 7 hours in total, no luck with different signing errors. From what I have found in the internet this is the best configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I added cocoa pods that were missing. I don't know how the build was successful from Cordova cli???

Second one of my plugins in particular admit-plus was not in the latest version in the config.xml

Fixing those two and everything worked!!!!!

Comment: Approve your own answer if this helped

Comment: there is a time limit before I can approve it. I'll do so when it passes

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper "work around" to push to test flight.

```
1- cordova prepare ios
2- open xcode project, uncheck automatic signing (both dev & release)
3- check back automatic signing
4- select your team
5- cordova build ios
6- build your app from xcode and test on device/simulator
7- from xcode: product -> archive
8- upload your build to appstoreconnect via xcode
9- go to appstoreconnect, then from there put it in test flight
```

Comment: Thank you Eric it did not solve my problem but it helped greatly to solve it especially the prepare command that showed that cocoa pods were not installed (don't ask why build from the Cordova cli was successful)